# Fitting html content to page issue, after converting PDF to HTML using Aspose library

Tags: java, html, aspose

I am using the Aspose library to convert PDF to HTML. But after conversion, I am facing a page fitting issue. On browser HTML file shows a white area on the right side. Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this issue?

**Reference Link:**  https://docs.aspose.com/pdf/java/convert-pdf-to-html-format/

**Code Snippet:**

```
            doc.setFitWindow(true);
            doc.getPageInfo().setLandscape(true);
            // Instantiate HTML Save options object
            HtmlSaveOptions newOptions = new HtmlSaveOptions();
            // Enable option to embed all resources inside the HTML
            newOptions.PartsEmbeddingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.PartsEmbeddingModes.EmbedAllIntoHtml;
            newOptions.LettersPositioningMethod = LettersPositioningMethods.UseEmUnitsAndCompensationOfRoundingErrorsInCss;
            newOptions.RasterImagesSavingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.RasterImagesSavingModes.AsEmbeddedPartsOfPngPageBackground;
            newOptions.FontSavingMode = HtmlSaveOptions.FontSavingModes.SaveInAllFormats;
            newOptions.setConvertMarkedContentToLayers(true);
            // Output file path
            String outHtmlFileName = new StringBuilder(source.getName().replaceAll(Constant.PDF_EXTENSION, "")).append(Constant.DASH).append(System.currentTimeMillis()).append(Constant.HTML_EXTENSION).toString();
            String outFileName = new StringBuilder(targetDirectory).append(Constant.SLASH).append(outHtmlFileName).toString();
            // Save the output file
            doc.save(outFileName, newOptions);
```

[image]

Comment: Please try using newOptions.setFixedLayout(false), and make sure to use the latest version of the API i.e. 21.3. If the issue still persists, try to share your sample PDF document by creating a post in the official Aspose.PDF Support Forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) where it can be properly addressed and resolved. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: @AsadAli I have tried newOptions.setFixedLayout(false) but not able to see images from PDF. Also, some PDFs have a space issue.

Comment: the issue you are facing needs to be properly investigated, and as requested earlier, the official support forum is the right place to discuss such cases. Please try to create a post there along with sample source file(s). We will further proceed to assist you accordingly. You can also upload the sample file to Google Drive or Dropbox and share the link with us.